# Sharepoint: list does not exist. Which list?

Tags: 2007

When I try to access the cache settings for my site at the url http://my.site.com/site/_Layouts/areacachesettings.aspx I get the error below.

There is nothing more in the url and I really have no idea which list is being mentioned here. The only one I can think of is **Cache Profiles** and that one is there when I check with Sharepoint Manager...

Any ideas?

```
     List does not exist 

     The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. 
     It may have been deleted by another user. 
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String 
bstrUrl,
     Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt,
     Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean
     bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, 
    ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount) 
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid
     foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32
     dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean 
    bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
     p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution at http://blogs.tamtam.nl/operational-services/2010/02/23/SiteCollectionOutputCacheListDoesNotExist.aspx .

In short the *Office Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* feature has to be deactivated and reactivated on the site collection to make this work again.

Comment: Also make sure viewstate is enabled in web.config

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. That page accesses a hidden list called "Cache Profiles" which may have been deleted somehow or there may be something wrong with it. Can you browse the site collection in SharePoint Manager tool and see if this list is present?